# how to install liblog4cxx10-dev in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install liblog4cxx10-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package liblog4cxx10-dev
```

An old project needs liblog4cxx10-dev to be installed, but apt-get can't find it. Dose it deprecated in Ubuntu18.04? Is there any work around ways?

Answer (score 3):

The package is `liblog4cxx-dev` and the corresponding binary is `liblog4cxx10v5` - both are version `0.10`